# How to make this generator work endlessly?

Tags: python

I need a cipher generator with letters and for it to work all the time since it was launched, but I do not understand how to do it.

```
import random
import string

text = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits if i != 5 else string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(64)]
print(''.join(text))

text = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits if i != 5 else string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(42)]
print(''.join(text))
```

It works only once when launched, but it is desirable that it is generated endlessly.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense; `while True:`, maybe?

Comment: didn't quite understand

Comment: You don't have any generators; you have a pair of list comprehensions. Do you want to define `text` so that repeated uses of `''.join(text)` produce different results?

Comment: Do you mean produce the **same** random sequence any number of times?

Comment: yes @user19077881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it from the response to my comment your issue is repeatedly producing the same random sequence for cryptographic uses. If so all you need to do is set a seed value each time the sequence is needed:

```
import random
import string

random.seed(77)
text = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits if i != 5 else string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(64)]
print(''.join(text))

random.seed(77)
text = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits if i != 5 else string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(64)]
print(''.join(text))

random.seed(77)
text = [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits if i != 5 else string.ascii_uppercase) for i in range(42)]
print(''.join(text))
```

which gives

```
qumpmDs49pj96arb5lm6ylvuhf9q84nomefm928egnvfg3f8gr29hw7dz7po4ziy
qumpmDs49pj96arb5lm6ylvuhf9q84nomefm928egnvfg3f8gr29hw7dz7po4ziy
qumpmDs49pj96arb5lm6ylvuhf9q84nomefm928egn
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to print random characters endlessly, it's going to have to be in an infinite loop. Generate *one* random character, then print it with `end=""` to suppress the newline. `flush=True` forces the character to be written to the console. Finally, `time.sleep` suspends the thread for a short time so that the OS doesn't think it's stopped responding.

```
import time
import random
import string

while True:
    char = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits if i != 5 else string.ascii_uppercase)
    print(char, end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

This will continue to print characters to your console until you interrupt it with a Ctrl+C KeyboardInterrupt

[image]

Comment: I have an error in virtual studio code

Comment: @VolodymyrKorud I can't help you with an error if you don't tell me what it is